# subdomain rewrite rule on apache (converted from nginx)

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, subdomain, rewrite

A friend of mine is moving hosts and I've been tasked with sorting out his rewrite rules. I've got most of them done, barring this awkward subdomain rewrite rule:

```
server {
listen   80;
server_name  ~^(?<subdomain>.+)\.foo\.gg$;

location / {
if (!-e $request_filename) {
    rewrite  ^/([-a-zA-Z0-9]+)-$  /stats.php?code=$1&sub=$subdomain  last;
    rewrite  ^/([-a-zA-Z0-9]+)$  /redirect.php?code=$1&sub=$subdomain  last;
    break;
}
}
}
```

I've tried this (from another serverfault thread, which doesn't work for me:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.foo\.gg$

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ redirect.php?code=$1&sub=$2 [L]
```

Help?

Answer (score 2):

The replace string needs to be adjusted to use the capture from the `RewriteCond`, and whether or not you need the leading slash depends on where this `RewriteRule` is configured - the way you have it means that it needs to be in the `<Directory>` block for the document root, or an `.htaccess` file there.

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ redirect.php?code=$1&sub=%1 [L]
```

If it's in your `<VirtualHost>` then keep the leading slash.

```
RewriteRule ^/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ redirect.php?code=$1&sub=%1 [L]
```

Comment: +1 for explaining when you need a trailing slash. I'm always having troubles with that with Apache.